# My computer doesn't lock after hibernating

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

How can I re-enable this feature? I have password on my account!

Comment: For what operating system?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Windows 7:

- Go to "Control Panel" → "Hardware and Sound" → "Power Options"
- Look for "Change Advanced Power Settings"

  - It may be under "Change when the computer sleeps"
  - Some systems may not have it
- Expand the top two options, and then set "Require a password on wakeup" to "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

IN WINDOWS 10 :
Go to Settings NOT CONTROL PANEL!
Then Accounts > sign-in options > require sign-in : when pc wakes up from sleep.